# My own version of `merge` method for hashes

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create my version of the `merge` method for hashes. This is one of the tests:

```
test_hash_1 = { a: 10, b: 2 }
test_hash_2 = { a: 5, b: 10, c: 3 }
test_hash_1.my_merge(test_hash_2) { |key, oldval, newval| newval - oldval } #=> {a: -5, b: 8, c: 3}
```

Like `Hash#merge`, the code needs to return an array of all the values of one specific key. For example:

```
test_hash_1 = { a: 10, b: 2 }
test_hash_2 = { b: 3, c: 4 }
expect { |b| test_hash_1.my_merge(test_hash_2, &b)}.to yield_successive_args([:b, 2, 3])
```

This is what I have:

```
def my_merge(hash2, &blk)
    new_hash = self    
    if block_given?
      hash2.each do |k1, v1|
        new_hash[k1] = blk.call
      end
    else
      hash2.each do |k2, v2|
        new_hash[k2] = v2
      end
    end
    new_hash
  end
end
```

I have some difficulty understanding how blocks work. My code is not close to what the expected outcome should be. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you give some sample input and expected output?

Comment: `test_hash_1.my_merge(test_hash_2) { |key, oldval, newval| newval - oldval } #=> {a: -5, b: 8, c: 3}`

Comment: Yes, that is also part of the problem. @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code:

```
def my_merge(hash2, &blk)
  # ...
end
```

Since you are not going to pass the block around, you don't have to specify the block argument explicitly. You can just define it as:

```
def my_merge(hash2)
  # ...
end
```

and use `yield(...)` instead of `blk.call(...)`.

---

You create `new_hash` via:

```
  new_hash = self
```

which will make `new_hash[k1] = ...` equivalent to `self[k1] = ...`. To avoid modifying the receiver, create a copy via [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) instead:

```
  new_hash = dup
```

Your first conditional checks whether a block is given or not. But according to the documentation, the block is only called for duplicate entries. So the actual conditional is: does the key exists *and* is a block given. And because it has to take the key into account, we have to move it into the `each` block:

```
  hash2.each do |k, v|
    if new_hash.key?(k) && block_given?
      new_hash[k] = yield(k, new_hash[k], v)
    else
      new_hash[k] = v
    end
  end
```

The 3 arguments we're passing via `yield` are key, old value and new value.

---

You may have noticed a pattern in your code:

```
def m(ary)
  obj = initial_value
  ary.each do |e|
    # modify obj
  end
  obj
end
```

This can be expressed more concise by using [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def m(ary)
  ary.each_with_object(initial_value) do |e, o|
    # modify obj
  end
end
```

---

The whole code:

```
class Hash
  def my_merge(hash)
    hash.each_with_object(dup) do |(k, v), h|
      if h.key?(k) && block_given?
        h[k] = yield(k, h[k], v)
      else
        h[k] = v
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `each_with_object(dup)` is a nice touch. Have catalogued that in the little grey cells.

Answer (score 1):

See [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) for requirements.

```
class Hash
  def my_merge(h)
    keys.each_with_object({}) do |k,g|
      g[k] = if h.key?(k)
               block_given? ? yield(k, self[k], h[k]) : h[k]
             else
               self[k]
             end
    end.tap { |g| (h.keys-keys).each { |k| g[k] = h[k] } }
  end
end

h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
g = {       b: 3, c: 4, d: 5 }        

h.my_merge(g)                 #=> {:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>4, :d=>5}
h.merge(g)                    #=> {:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>4, :d=>5}

h.my_merge(g) { |_,o,n| o+n } #=> {:a=>1, :b=>5, :c=>7, :d=>5}
h.merge(g)    { |_,o,n| o+n } #=> {:a=>1, :b=>5, :c=>7, :d=>5}
```

`merge` does not return arrays of values of common keys, but it can be used with a particular block to do that:

```
h.my_merge(g) { |_,o,v| [o, v] } #=> {:a=>1, :b=>[2, 3], :c=>[3, 4], :d=>5}
h.merge(g)    { |_,o,v| [o, v] } #=> {:a=>1, :b=>[2, 3], :c=>[3, 4], :d=>5}
```

For readers unfamiliar with [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-tap), without it I would need to write the method something like the following.

```
def my_merge(h)
  g = keys.each_with_object({}) do |k,g|
    g[k] = if h.key?(k)
             block_given? ? yield(k, self[k], h[k]) : h[k]
           else
             self[k]
           end
  end
  (h.keys-keys).each { |k| g[k] = h[k] }
  g
end
```

Comment: You can use `h.merge(g) { |_, o, v| [o, v] }` to group duplicate elements in an array – no need for splat.